# laravel Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, constraints

Hey guys I tried too much stuff and read some blogs or discussion I didn't fix my problem I'm new in laravel this project for my university lesson...I got error when I want to create to database this error like

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `moviestore`.`#sql-  
13df8_27` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL:  
alter table `orders` add constraint `orders_address_id_foreign` foreign ke  
y (`address_id`) references `addresses` (`id`))
```

and this is my codes

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->dateTime('OrderDate');
        $table->integer('TotalCount');
        $table->decimal('TotalPrice',20,2);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
    });

   // Schema::table('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
   // {
   //     $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
   //     $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
   // });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
}
```

Addresses Table Code

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('FullAddress');
        $table->string('AddressType');
        $table->string('PhoneNumber');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('addresses');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
}
```

There is no relationship between each tables when I migrate tables
[image]

Comment: can you post the migration that being referred by `$table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');`? the table that have the primary key.

Comment: @BagusTesa This is github repo link https://github.com/emresandikci/moviestore-laravel

Comment: thats... weird.. i can't see anything wrong, i thought it was one of them either `bigIncrements` or `smallIncrements`.. need another pair of eyes to check this.

Comment: wait a minute! just realised that **timestamp** for the files are in the wrong order! `2017_05_04_115950_create_addresses_table.php` comes before `2017_05_04_115721_create_orders_table.php`. you have to make sure the dependent table (in this case `orders`) come after the the table (`addresses`) that it referred. glad you shared your project, it made checking easier. cheers!

Comment: @BagusTesa Thanks for your help but I didnt understand exactly what I need to do fix it

Comment: Drop all tables manually, rename the file timestamp and ensure the dependent table appear in right order, run composer dumpautoload, and run the migration

Comment: @Chay22 I did it and all table create I didnt get any error but this time there is not relations on ER diagram so what do you think ? I edited my post check the ss how looks like please

Comment: the `address` table created **after** `orders` table while `orders` table refers to `address` table foreign key, hence you got an error.. in Laravel, you had to order the table creation using the timestamp. So, basically, try to change the timestamp part of the migration file - **2017_05_04_115950**_create_addresses_table.php. easier example, look at [this repo](https://bitbucket.org/BagusTesa/ashadi-delivery-system-ads/src/f4bfdca18e87b3c38b802359b3c30db45d99ba2e/database/migrations/?at=master) also, re-read the [docs also](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#generating-migrations).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your migration file like:

First you  run `Addresses` migration because `Addresses.id` is foreign key of `orders.address_id`

*Addresses Table Code*

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('FullAddress');
        $table->string('AddressType');
        $table->string('PhoneNumber');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('addresses');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
}
```

*Orders table*

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->dateTime('OrderDate');
        $table->integer('TotalCount');
        $table->decimal('TotalPrice',20,2);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses')->onDelete('cascade');
    });


}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
}
```

Comment: I did it and all table create I didnt get any error but this time there is not relations on ER diagram so what do you think ? I edited my post check the ss how looks like please